# How to merge two 2D string arrays into one in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d

I want to merge two string arrays into one array:

array 1:

```
firstnames[NUMBER_NAMES][LEN_NAME] = {"luca","tomas"}
```

and array 2:

```
secondname[NUMBER_NAMES][LEN_NAMES] = {"goirgi", "edison"}
```

and i want to put them in an array where the first name and last name can be together

Comment: OK, so what's the question?  What did you try?  What didn't work?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: So just hang on and try doing that by yourself and then show your code please!

Comment: @CarlNorum  Thank for the reply. My project is bigger than this. I have do do additions in 1D arrays and then assign those values to people (names). I was find trouble only in this how to merge two string arrays into one array . What I has tried was this :

Comment: @CarlNorum 
'
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN_NAME 34
#define NUM_NAMES 2

int main (void)

{
    char firstName[NUM_NAMES] ={"luca","tomas"} ;
    char lastName[NUM_NAMES] ={"goirgi", "edison"};
    char fullName[NUM_NAMES]
    int i;

    {
        strcpy (fullName, firstName);
        strcat (fullName, "  " );
        strcat (fullName, lastName);
        printf("Your full name is %s.\n", fullName);
'
now I see my mistake, I was declaring single dimension arrays.

Thank you very much , I appreciate your effort

Comment: @SteveP. 
Thank you, I already did.

This website is so awesome , and very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, include :

```
#include <string.h>
```

Now, let the string be stored in names[NUMBER_NAMES][LEN_NAMES]

```
char name[sNUMBER_NAMES][LEN_NAMES];
```

Finally, a for loop for each element in the array:

```
for(i=0;i<NUMBER_NAMES;i++)
 { strcpy(names[i],firstnames[i]); //To initialize ith names element with first name
   strcat(names[i])," ");          //To concatanate a space between the 2 names   
   strcat(names[i]),lastnames[i]); //Concatanate the last name to the firstname+ space string
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful.
`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN_NAME 34
#define NUM_NAMES 2

int main (void)

{
    char firstName[NUM_NAMES] ={"luca","tomas"} ;
    char lastName[NUM_NAMES] ={"goirgi", "edison"};
    char fullName[NUM_NAMES]
    int i;

    {
        strcpy (fullName, firstName);
        strcat (fullName, "  " );
        strcat (fullName, lastName);
        printf("Your full name is %s.\n", fullName);
`

Now I see that i was declaring One dimensional arrays .

thank you very much I appreciate your help .